# How to handle unexpected connection close in aio pika

Tags: python, python-pika

do you have any clues on how to handle an unexpected connection close of Rabbit? Pika handles it by itself and tries every 5 seconds to reconnect. I don't need such behavior; it should raise an exception that closes the service instead. I've been searching for an answer, but unfortunately, I haven't found anything.

```
class AMQPHandler:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.connection: AbstractRobustConnection | None = None
        self.channel: AbstractChannel | None = None

    async def init(self) -> None:
        import settings

        # breakpoint()
        logger.info("Initializing AMQP handler")

        config = settings.BaseMessageBrokerSettings
        connection = await aio_pika.connect_robust(
            config.get_dsn(),
            loop=asyncio.get_event_loop(),
            timeout=config.CONNECTION_TIMEOUT,
        )
        channel = await connection.channel()

        await channel.set_qos(prefetch_count=10)

        exchange = await channel.declare_exchange(
            config.EXCHANGE_NAME,
            config.EXCHANGE_TYPE,
            auto_delete=config.EXCHANGE_AUTO_DELETE,
            durable=True,
        )
        for key in config.BINDING_KEYS:
            q_name = (
                f"{key}.{config.PREFIX_BINDING_KEYS}"
                if config.PREFIX_BINDING_KEYS
                else key
            )
            queue = await channel.declare_queue(name=q_name, durable=True)
            await queue.bind(exchange, q_name)
            await queue.consume(self.handle_message)
            logger.info("Queue declared", extra={"queue": q_name})

        self.connection = connection
        self.channel = channel

        logger.info("AMQP handler initialized")
```